# MYSQL SUM of Month to Date Sum Grouped By Day

Tags: mysql

Trying to calculate month to date revenue entered into the system for every day of the year by market. Current query works but it keeps timing out within my BI tool's mysql instance (set to 15 min). My BI tool may also not allow for mysql variables and if they do it would have to be conditional. I would ideally like to add more conditions.

```
/* Current query with subquery, this works syntactically, but is inefficient*/
SELECT  
    d.`Event Date`,
    d.`market`,
    (SELECT SUM(s.`Revenue`)
     FROM time_from_start s
     WHERE s.`created` <= d.`Event Date`
     AND s.`Month/Year` = d.`Month/Year`
     AND s.`market` = d.`market`) as 'Revenue to Date'
FROM time_from_start d
GROUP BY d.`Event Date`,d.market
```

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. Please add some sample input and expected output in order to make your requirement lucid.

Comment: Apologies, this is my first time trying this. I'm not sure what you mean by expected output. Can you elaborate? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using a query that avoids the use of a correlated subquery by using a self join instead.

This query should give the same results as your original query:

```
SELECT d1.`Event Date`, d1.market, SUM(d2.Revenue) AS Revenue_to_date
FROM time_from_start d1
LEFT JOIN time_from_start d2
ON d2.market = d1.market
AND d2.`Month/Year` = d1.`Month/Year`
AND d2.created <= d1.`Event Date`
GROUP BY d1.`Event Date`, d1.market
```

Also, make sure that there are indexes on the columns used in the query.